# Executing command 'ADB devices' on electron js in cmd line using exec()

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron, electron-builder, electron-packager

I'm using electron js and I'm a bit newbie in it.

As per my knowledge, we can use all `npm` package as we can use in `nodejs`.
So, I am using `'node-command-line'` package in it.

Now, when I'm building the code in mac using `'electron-builder'`, commands like `adb devices` are working perfectly when I launch the application with `npm start`. But after building it in mac its throwing me an error, saying adb devices command not found with the same process.

PFB the code:

```
var cmd     = require('node-command-line'),Promise = require('bluebird');
function runSingleCommandWithoutWait() {
    let listener=cmd.run('adb devices');
    listener.then(function(value_listener){  
        //SOME FUNCTION
    });
   }
```

When i build-l , it works in linux but not build -m is not working in mac system. It shows `adb devices command not found`.

This executes the command once I run it by default in `/bin/sh`. The path of adb in both the system has been set similar as applicable to each.

How I make the command run in mac? 
Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: Have you tried specifying the full path to adb

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using [adbkit](https://github.com/openstf/adbkit)?

*From adbkit GitHub:*

> adbkit is a pure Node.js client for the Android Debug Bridge server. It can be used either as a library in your own application, or simply as a convenient utility for playing with your device.
>
> Most of the adb command line tool's functionality is supported (including pushing/pulling files, installing APKs and processing logs)